# -webkit-background-clip:text and transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2.1) on the same element causing a conflict

Tags: html, css

I have an element that I am using `transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2.1);` in order to create a parallax scrolling effect. But I am also trying to add a text clip over the image in that element using `-webkit-background-clip:text;` and relevant properties. The text clip works when I disable transform, but the parallax stops working as would be expected. But when the transform is enabled the text clip disappears. Is this a z-index issue? How can I resolve it?

relevant CSS:

```css
html {
          scroll-behavior: smooth;
        }
html, body{overflow:hidden;}

*, :before, :after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parallax {
                  position:relative;
                height: 500px; /* fallback for older browsers */
                height: 100vh;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: auto;
                -webkit-perspective: 300px;
                perspective: 300px;
                  scroll-behavior: smooth;
              }
              .parallax__group {
                position: relative;
                height: 500px; /* fallback for older browsers */
                height: 100vh;
                -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                transform-style: preserve-3d;
              }
              .parallax__layer {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
              }
    
/*  Disabling the transforms in the following class will enable the text clipping, but disable the parallax */


              .parallax__layer--back {
                -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2.1);
                transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2.1);
                /*z-index: -3;*/
              }
#group2 .parallax__layer--back {
            
                  background-image: url('https://png.pngtree.com/background/20210712/original/pngtree-modern-double-color-futuristic-neon-background-picture-image_1181573.jpg');
                 background-size: cover;
                 height: 100vh;
                 overflow: hidden;
                 left:0;
              }
        .gap{
            height:auto;
            min-height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
            background: #fff; 
            position: relative; 
            z-index: 4;
            -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            display: flex; 
            flex-flow: column; 
            align-content: center; 
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
/* Clip text element */
.clip-text {
    font-size: 10vh;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 45vh 15%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--color8);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.clip-text:before,
.clip-text:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  
}

/* Background */
.clip-text:before {
  z-index: -2;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: inherit;
    background-size:cover;
}

/* Text Background */
.clip-text:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 25%;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 25%;
  left: 15%;
  background-color: #fff;
    opacity:.6;
}
```

```html
<HTML>
<body>
<div class="parallax">  
 <div id="group2" class="parallax__group">
             
              <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back clip-text ">
                  Brand
              </div>
    </div>
<div class="gap">Some text goes here</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Really unclear what you are trying to accomplish here. If I load your code snippet, I see two scrollbars and a picture. No Paralax, no Text-Clip. Please post a minimal reproducible example, probably with comments on what to disable to understand the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @rx2347 I'm sorry! Missed a block of code in my copy, I have updated it to function with the issue illustrated, and I have added a comment above the CSS class that needs to be modified to see the text clipping (but disables the parallax). My goal is to have the title with the text clipping inside the opaque box, and have the parallax effect functioning.